# Grepping filenames from .txt files that are located in subdirectory and joining them with filename of a file that is located in directory

Tags: bash

I have a directory containing 60k subdirectories.
Each subdirectory has two (sub-)subdirectories (`2_4`, `cov_bound`). What I am interested in is subdirectory `2_4`. So it looks like this:

```
main_directory/foo/2_4/
```

Each subdirectory `foo` contains one `.pdb` file.
Each `2_4` subsubdirectory contains 0 or more `.txt` files.

So it looks like this:

```
main_directory/foo/1A2C.pdb
main_directory/foo/2_4/XLS#A#207.txt
main_directory/foo/2_4/XLS#B#209.txt
main_directory/foo/2_4/XLS#C#207.txt
main_directory/foo/2_4/SOS#D#145.txt
```

I am trying to join the letters before the first `#` in the filename (`XLS`, `SOS` in this example) into the file name of the pdb file:

```
1A2C_XLS_SOS.pdb
```

Multiple files start with `XLS#`, but each prefix should only be used once.

The second problem that I was encountering is that if the subdirectory `2_4` is empty, it gives an output as `1A2C_.pdb` and I want to get rid of this. So if `2_4` is empty, don't process it. Just run it on the `2_4` subdirectories that have `.txt` files.

I was trying to write something in bash but this works only for one `.txt` file in `2_4` and it also takes into account empty `2_4`.

All these pdb files with new filenames should be copied into another directory.

I have tried this in bash:

```
mkdir pdb_files
for i in */ ; do cd $i ; pwd ; a=`head -n1 2_4/*txt | awk '{print $4}' ` ; j=`ls *pdb` ;  cp $j ../pdb_files/${j//.pdb/_$a}.pdb ; cd ../ ; done
```

I was running it from the `main_directory`.

Comment: I was trying to clean up your `crazy` random `code` formatted `words`, but I had to stop because I realized I actually have no idea what you're trying to say. What is this question?

Comment: I also removed the `perl` tag because I don't see anything related to Perl here.

Comment: have you read it? tell me what you didn't understand I am happy to describe it better :)

Comment: Let's start with your "directory with different number of subdirectories". How can a directory have a different number of subdirectories? Different from what? Itself?

Comment: So what I was trying to say is that I have `main_directory` and inside the `main_directory`I have 60k of directories.

Comment: OK, that's the first paragraph taken care of. What is a "subdiretory"? What's with `(\`pdb file\`)`?

Comment: `Subdirectory` I am refering to a `directory` that is located within another directory (`main_directory`). Each `subdirectory (out of 60k)` surely has one `.pdb file`

Comment: Please `stop` formatting `random` words `as` code. `Why` are `you` doing `that`?

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted to label important words.

Comment: I rewrote your question a bit. Does it still match what you're trying to do?

Comment: @melpomene Yes, it still matches what I want and it looks much better. Thank You for thisuseful suggestion and changes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a crack at it:

```
TARGETDIR=./pdb_files
for dir in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -name .)
do
  PREFIXES=( $(
    for file in ${dir}/2_4/*.txt
    do
      filename=$(basename $file)
      echo ${filename%%\#*.txt}
    done | sort -u 
  ) )

  if [ ${PREFIXES[0]} != '*.txt' ]
  then
    for oldpdb in ${dir}/*.pdb
    do
      pdbname=${oldpdb%%.pdb}
      pdbsuffix=$(IFS=_ ; echo "${PREFIXES[*]}")
      newpdb=${TARGET}/$(basename $pdbname)_${pdbsuffix}.pdb
      echo -------------------------
      echo Directory: $dir
      echo Old file name: $oldpdb
      echo New file name: $newpdb
      # I think this is what you want?
      cp $oldpdb $newpdb
    done
  else
    for oldpdb in ${dir}/*.pdb
    do
      echo -------------------------
      echo Directory: $dir
      echo Old file name: $oldpdb
      echo New file name: do not rename file
      # maybe you want to copy unmodified files?
      # cp $oldpdb $TARGET
    done
  fi
done
```

This is my directory structure, from main_directory:

```
main_directory/
├── foo
│   ├── 1A2C.pdb
│   └── 2_4
│       ├── SOS#D#145.txt
│       ├── XLS#A#207.txt
│       ├── XLS#B#209.txt
│       └── XLS#C#207.txt
├── foo2
│   ├── 1A2B.pdb
│   └── 2_4
└── run
```

And, the output from './run' in main_directory:

```
-------------------------
Directory: ./foo2
Old file name:
New file name: do not rename file
-------------------------
Directory: ./foo
Old file name: ./foo/1A2C.pdb
New file name: ./foo/1A2C_SOS_XLS.pdb
```

EDIT:  I had missed the "copy these new files to some other directory" bit, so I tweaked the script a bit.

EDIT 2:  Kudos to melpomene; sorry to steal your question, by the time I got here you had cleaned it up well enough that it made sense.  Sorry :(

EDIT 3:  Well, it isn't super clear exactly what you want to do with these files.  The hard part seemed to bet getting the correct new file name, I think this code does that.  I've changed it so it just prints out the old and new PDB filenames, from there you can insert your own logic to rename or copy them around as you see fit?   This script doesn't `cd` into each directory, it does everything from the main directory.  Please give it a try with a subset of your data and let me know how it goes.

EDIT 4:  Changed logic on where we move the new file

EDIT 5:  Put some problematic code here.  Here's code without all of the debug / attempt to demonstrate the inner workings of the script.  This will do what you're after and not talk about what it's doing along the way.

EDIT 6:  My previous code didn't work for directories that had one .txt file.  This will work for all use cases I'm aware of.

```
#!/bin/bash

TARGETDIR=./pdb_files

for dir in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -name .)
do
  PREFIXES=( $(
    for file in ${dir}/2_4/*.txt
    do
      filename=$(basename $file)
      echo ${filename%%\#*.txt}
    done | sort -u
  ) )

  if [ ${#PREFIXES[@]} -ge 1 -a "${PREFIXES[0]}" != '*.txt' ]
  then
    for oldpdb in ${dir}/*.pdb
    do
      pdbname=${oldpdb%%.pdb}
      pdbsuffix=$(IFS=_ ; echo "${PREFIXES[*]}")
      newpdb=${TARGETDIR}/$(basename $pdbname)_${pdbsuffix}.pdb
      cp $oldpdb $newpdb
    done
  fi
done
```

Tree before:

```
main_directory
├── foo
│   ├── 1A2C.pdb
│   └── 2_4
│       ├── SOS#D#145.txt
│       ├── XLS#A#207.txt
│       ├── XLS#B#209.txt
│       └── XLS#C#207.txt
├── foo2
│   ├── 1A2B.pdb
│   └── 2_4
├── foo3
│   ├── 2_4
│   │   └── XLS#C#100.csv
│   └── 2A3B.pdb
├── foo4
│   ├── 2_4
│   │   └── XLS#D#201.txt
│   └── 3A3B.pdb
├── pdb_files
└── run
```

After:

```
main_directory
├── foo
│   ├── 1A2C.pdb
│   └── 2_4
│       ├── SOS#D#145.txt
│       ├── XLS#A#207.txt
│       ├── XLS#B#209.txt
│       └── XLS#C#207.txt
├── foo2
│   ├── 1A2B.pdb
│   └── 2_4
├── foo3
│   ├── 2_4
│   │   └── XLS#C#100.csv
│   └── 2A3B.pdb
├── foo4
│   ├── 2_4
│   │   └── XLS#D#201.txt
│   └── 3A3B.pdb
├── pdb_files
│   ├── 1A2C_SOS_XLS.pdb
│   └── 3A3B_XLS.pdb
└── run
```

Comment: Logic seems to be good, but it miss to copy the files to copy renamed files into another directory. I am not sure that the paths are correct as well. So it has to be ran from `main_directory`.

Comment: Thanks for the script. It compiles fine and give correct output pdb names.. is it possible to change it in a way that these renamed pdb files are moved to some other directory ( names doesnt matter)?

Comment: Maybe for my example directory structure, show how you want things to look when the script is done?  Put that into your question?  Or, create your own starting and desired ending directory structure?

Comment: Yeah script works for great mine directory structure as well..just to add to move this `renamed pdb files` into another directory `pdb_files` that can be located in the `main_directory` :)

Comment: so I have checked it now on the smaller data-set like `50 pdb files`. Script compiles well, but two problems I am encountering: 1. If `2_4` folder is empty > output of the script for this pdb file is for example 1A2C_.pdb. So these `2_4` folders that are empty, that doesn't ahve .txt file/files should not be processed. Second thing is that I have made directory `pdb_files` inside the `main_directory` and for some reason this line `cp $newpdb $TARGET` doesn't copy them into the `pdb_files` directory?

Comment: So, as I've seen someone post somewhere else, this isn't a code writing service, you are expected to put some effort into this yourself as well. That said, it may not be super clear why empty folders are putting out modified PDB filenames, so I'll update my script with some modified logic (it's because there's no .txt files, but there are other files in that 2_4 directory).  I'll also check the $TARGET again.  But, the larger expectation is that once you get through the block that is preventing you from moving ahead, you adapt the technique you learned and move on with solving your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried to modify it and to modify the target destination, and to add move instead of cp but for some reason files weren't moved although by looking at it it seems to fulfill the logic we want. Yeah, because these folders are empty (no txt files) the output is wrong as well. I have been thinking how to change it..maybe by eding one more big loop with conditions of testing only those `2_4` folders that are not empty..these `2_4` folders will surely have only txt files.

Comment: Edit 6 has code that should work.  Good luck with this.